# How to evaluate hyperbolic functions, involving inverses, by hand?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

How does one evaluate $$\sinh(2{\sinh^{-1}{(2)}})$$
by hand?

Comment: $\sin$ double angle formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\sinh(2x)=2\sinh x \cosh x$$

then use that

- $ \sinh(\operatorname{arsinh}x) = x  $
- $ \cosh(\operatorname{arsinh}x) = \sqrt{1+x^{2}}  $